# CollectionChanged notification across threads?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm writing a download manager using C#/WPF, and I just encountered this error:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

The basic flow of my program is that a few web pages/downloads are enqueued at the start, and then they're downloaded asynchronously. When an HTML page has completed downloading, I parse it and look for more stuff to download, then enqueue it directly from within the worker thread.

I get that error when trying to send out the `CollectionChanged` event on my customized queue class. However, I need to fire that event so that the GUI can get updated.

What are my options?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137769/wpf-where-do-i-get-a-threadsafe-collectionview

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261248/wpf-thread-and-gui-how-to-access-object-from-different-thread

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) from Microsoft, they're designed for just this sort of thing.  They create "observable collections" and are useful in paralell and multi-core scenarios.

**UPDATE:**

You may also find the [SyncronizationContext](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/SyncContextTutorial.aspx) useful as well.  That's a Windows Forms sample, but there are variations for WPF as well.

Comment: Looks interesting... but I have no idea to use it, and there doesn't seem to be any documentation aside from a few videos which don't directly address my issue. Hrm..

Comment: From what I grasp, I should basically convert an enumerable into an observable... but I really have no idea how that works. Observables are supposed to fire events when an item is changed/removed, but enumerables don't do that... collections do. How is Rx clever enough to know how to fire the appropriate events then? Baffles me.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure that you use the Dispatcher for the relevant thread to invoke any code that updates the collection, or fires the event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx

**Update**

The Dispatcher is a property on all of the classes that derive from DispatcherObject, which includes all DependencyObjects, Visuals, etc.

So, your GUI objects will all have a Dispatcher property.

Comment: In that article, they write Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                    new Action<string>(SetStatus), 
                    "From Other Thread"); which looks like it might be what I need to do for queuing. But where is this `Dispatcher` defined? And how does it know what thread to sync with?

Comment: Well...it gets slightly farther before crashing now. Turns out my `DownloadManager` itself does some cross-thread enqueues, but it's created through the XAML and I don't have access to a dispatcher from inside it. Not quite sure what to do now.

Comment: Actually, if I derive from DispatcherObject and then put `private Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;` in my class, and use that it runs for a good 10 seconds before it crashes w/out exception or stack trace! Hurray!

Comment: Try DispatcherPriority.Background or other lower priorities

Comment: Naw, I'm sure there's a problem somewhere in my code... and I don't want it to be lower priority. It's an important operation :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I had to deal with collection change notifications across threads, I always turned to [How can I propagate changes across threads](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=34) blog article for help.

I am not sure from the context of your question if this can indeed help you, but if your collection is something you directly control, you can benefit from this.

Comment: Doesn't explain how to *Dequeue* elements from a collection :(

Comment: I re-read your question and I am unsure what exactly is your dequeuing problem. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: The problem was that in that blog post, she only covers methods that return `void`. `BeginInvoke` doesn't work so well when you actually need to return a value.